# JOOQ PostgreSQL access a single element of an array

Tags: postgresql, jooq

TO get a single element in PostgreSQL query, we can do something like

```
SELECT pay_by_quarter[3] FROM sal_emp;
```

or in case of a condition,

```
SELECT * FROM sal_emp WHERE pay_by_quarter[1] = 10000
```

How can I achieve the same thing in JOOQ, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pending feature request to allow for referencing array elements by index through jOOQ API: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/229

The workaround is to use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/):

```java
public static <T> Field<T> get(Field<T[]> field, int index) {
    return (Field) DSL.field(
        "{0}[{1}]", 
        field.getDataType().getType().getComponentType(), 
        val(index)
    );
}
```